# BrowserSync: Proxy Subdomains

Tags: django, gulp, frontend, browser-sync

I have a Django app which serves multiple sites on separate subdomains. In development, I access the sites on:

- www.myapp.local:8000
- data.myapp.local:8000
- publish.myapp.local:8000
- admin.myapp.local:8000

> Note this works using the [django_hosts](https://github.com/jazzband/django-hosts) library and through modifying */etc/hosts* file, e.g:
>
> ```
> 127.0.0.1 www.myapp.local
> 127.0.0.1 data.myapp.local
> 127.0.0.1 publish.myapp.local
> 127.0.0.1 admin.myapp.local
> ```

However, I am unable to figure out how to configure BrowserSync, in my Gulp-based workflow, in order to proxy all subdomains, providing a seamless experience as I navigate around the sites, and reload the browser as I develop.

Configuring BrowserSync to proxy the main site, e.g.

```
browserSync.init(
    [paths.css + "/*.css", paths.js + "*.js", paths.templates + '/**/*.html'], {
    proxy: 'www.myapp.local:8000' 
})
```

only 'captures' the main site, if you click a link to one of the subdomains, you navigate out of the BrowserSync session and will be served directly by Django on port 8000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this to work perfectly using a combination of [middleware](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options#option-middleware) (using [http-proxy-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware)) and [rewriteRules](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options#option-rewriteRules):

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware'),

browserSync.init([paths.css + "/*.css", paths.js + "*.js", paths.templates + '/**/*.html'], {
    middleware: [
        function (req, res, next) {
            let target = 'http://' + req.headers.host.replace('myapp.local:3000', 'myapp.local:8000');
            proxy({
                target,
                changeOrigin: true
            })(req, res, next);
        }
    ],
    rewriteRules: [
        {
            match: /myapp.local:8000/g,
            fn: function (req, res, match) {
                return 'myapp.local:3000';
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

The middleware matches any url with the parent domain,`myapp.local:3000`, and proxies the request to port 8000 listened to by Django without changing the subdomain. The rewriteRules are used to rewrite any links in the response, so subsequent navigation is correctly reversed back through the proxy.