# How do I proxy domains AND subdomains with browsersync?

Tags: browser-sync, http-proxy-middleware

I currently proxy my dev machine like this:

```
   bs.init({
        proxy: "http://localtest.me:80",
        port: 81,
        open: true,
        notify: false
    });
```

I need to route all subdomain requests to the same server:port with the subdomain intact.  How do I use http-proxy-middleware to do this today?  The following doesn't work (per [BrowserSync: Proxy Subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56295613/browsersync-proxy-subdomains) 11 months ago) ...

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');
const bs = require('browser-sync').create();

    bs.init({
        proxy: {
                middleware: [
                    function (req, res, next) {
                        let target = 'http://' + req.headers.host.replace('localtest.me:81', 'localtest.me:80');
                        proxy({
                            target,
                            changeOrigin: true
                        })(req, res, next);
                    }
                ]
                ,rewriteRules: [
                    {
                        match: /localtest.me:80/g,
                        fn: function (req, res, match) {
                            return 'localtest.me:81';
                        }
                    }
                ]

        },
        open: true,
        notify: false
    });
```